# Is there a way to get more than 259 characters on a TreeNode?

Tags: c#, winforms, treenode

I'm making a treeView and some of the names of my nodes have more than 259 characters, but it just takes the first 259 characters of the name. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: How to fix it? Use usable names.

Comment: I'm with Henk on this one. Can you provide an example why you need a 259+ character name? This goes against most design principles about keeping things standard and efficient.

Comment: @Grambot: I'm with abw333 on this one. I've just found a use case where debugging a complicated tree structure can really benefit from using more than 259 chars. Here's a sample of what I'm talking about: https://i.imgur.com/DP0mKzj.png

Comment: @DanW man, this is a 11 year old topic. TreeNode.Text property simply has a 259 character limit to the display. If you're trying to *show* more than that you're probably better off rolling something where the TreeNode display value is a key to some object collection that is displayed elsewhere. Source for the display limit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.text